# How are you supposed to let colleagues know when you are not in the office?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, out-of-office

At work we are all using outlook. But I am pretty sure that we are using it in the wrong way.

If we have a day off or go on holiday, we are to schedule an appointment and invite all relevant people to that appointment.

I used to uncheck a certain box that attendees could answer. I believe this would just set the appointment in their calendars without annoying e-mail notifications were one could accept or decline.

Now we have had another software update all is changed and I can't find that box anymore.

We also dislike that you get a reminder pop-up in Outlook when somebody is free on that day.

My boss has reserved every friday off, but as he works 50 hours a week. We get a standard cancellation mail every thursday around 21:00. And if he actually stays at home, we get a meeting reminder pop-up every friday morning.

We want to notify eachother with days off n such in the outlook calander. Without receiving E-mails or get any pop-up reminders. We just want to create a small note or something in everybody's calander and that is it. No mails, no reminders.

How is one supposed to use outlook for days off?

Comment: When I send an invitation to others about my holiday, I make sure that the time is shown as "free", no reminder is set and the response options "request responses" and "allow new time proposals" are unchecked. This ensures that my holiday is nothing more obtrusive than an entry at the top of their calendar. I then add a second entry in my own calendar with the time marked as "out of office" for people trying to schedule a meeting. It's messy, but it works.

Comment: @Richard Why add a second entry?  Just change the entry you already created to "out of office" after sending it out.  Also, nowadays you may also need to press 'Don't Host Online'.  This is something my colleagues sometimes forget!

Comment: @Stewart Good point, thanks! I think it's because I (incorrectly) assume it'll change the availability for others.

Answer (score 3):

Just create appointment without inviting anyone.
Or use built-in option to create all-day event:

1. Mark time you're OoO. RMB -> Create all-day event
   [image]
2. Set status to "Out-of-Office"
   [image]
   After that, you'll show in calendar as OoO. You'll also show as OoO in Teams, Outlook, etc. on the day you're out. You can also set OoO message: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/send-automatic-out-of-office-replies-from-outlook-9742f476-5348-4f9f-997f-5e208513bd67

To plan considering your status, other users can either:

1. Use option to import your calendar (in Outlook calendar view > Home > Add Calendar). There is possibility that you'll need to use "Share calendar" option first (button to the right from "Add")
   [image]
   [image]
   When you import more calendars this way, you can view few of them at once, giving you quick overview for current team availability:
   [image]
2. Create a meeting or appointment containing you and go to Scheduling Assistant. There is status of all attendees
   [image]

Comment: The 'make an appointment, add people and use scheduling assistant' I understand. But this does not solve anything because you need to actively find out who is free and not when we just want to 'be' in eachother's calendar.

I am goint to try the share option with a co-worker... we really need to get us mailing lists

Comment: In this case, you're indeed probably be satisfied with shared calendars. After importing few of them you can view them at once and with your own calendar. I've added note about this in answer.

Answer (score 2):

“We want to notify each other with days off”—from your description it’s clear this is *not* what you want. You do not want to *notify* each other. That’s what you’re doing right now.

The “correct” way is to block only *your* calendar when you’re out of office, as described in [Aramil’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1771329). You can also edit permissions on your calendar to let others see more details about your appointments.

Another good idea is to create a shared calendar (for example in a MS Teams team) and put all your absences in there. You’d only need to look at one calendar then. However, personal calendars must still be blocked because otherwise Scheduling Assistant cannot work.

---

Putting Out of Office notes in another person’s calendar is objectively wrong in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If your organization use Teams, you will see the Out of Office status directly when you are going to chat with her/him:

[image]

Perhaps the above is what you need.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.